# Splitting compressed files with hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, compression, hadoop-streaming, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to process many large (>1GB) gzipped files using a Hadoop streaming job on Google's cloud platform.  The jobs keep running out of memory even on large memory machines.  I understand that I should compress them with LZO or uncompress them first to get around this.  I would like to either uncompress them or split them into smaller files using a Hadoop streaming job.  Is there any way to do this without running into memory issues?  If not, can you recommend another way to handle this without downloading my data first?

Thanks